# Can't reach ononesoftware.com on one computer on network

Tags: networking

Will occasionally, eventually, get non html version--never times out.
Works on other computers on network.
Happened after spybot immunization--did undo, then removed program and folders
Reloaded Java and Flash
Tried three browsers, emptied caches
Onone never heard of such a problem; Comcast said it was a Windows issue

Comment: If you had a malware infection prior, everything is not all right yet... probably time to wipe the drive and reinstall windows

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a malware that's configured a proxy for you, hijacked your hosts file, or poisoned your DNS cache.

I'm assuming you have MS Windows.  If so...

1. Check for a proxy

   Go to Start > Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings

   Clear all the options

   Click OK and Click OK again
2. Check the hosts file

   Go to Start > Type `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\` and hit Enter

   Open the **hosts** file with `Notepad` or `Wordpad` and verify it's empty or all lines start with #
3. Clear the DNS cache

   Go to Start > Type `CMD` and hit Enter

   Type `ipconfig /flushdns` and hit Enter

If none of these work for you, you will need to format your computer and reinstall your operating system.